# Multiple voltage dividers : finding resistances in a circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistance, voltage-divider, nodal-analysis, mesh-analysis

I have to set the battery voltage to 14.5V from the first divider, then from that I have to attenuate it to 1V to feed to the input of an op amp. Now [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/197105/multiple-voltage-dividers/197135#197135)  answer is inspiring but doesn't solve my purpose. Maximum I can assume the R2 & R4. R3 & R5 still unknown.

Please help.
[image]

Comment: It is not clear if the 14.5v is being produced by the voltage divider or a 14.5v battery.  If you just need a low current reference consider using a 78l05 chip to produce a regulated 5v and use a voltage divider off that to produce your 1v reference.  If this is a homework question, Show the givens as they are given and show your attempt to solve it.

Comment: One thing you should note about voltage dividers is that the divider current must dwarf the output current.  You should look up the input current of the op amp and size r4 and r5 to pass no less than 10 times that(100x is better).  Then figure out the ratio of r2 to r3 and size the resistors to pass another 10 to 100x.  Note that cascading voltage dividers will not increase accuracy and that is why I recommend a regulator.

Comment: You should be able to solve for R5 right way: R4 and R5 form a voltage divider that divides 14.5V down to 1V. This is independent of R2 and R3. Now that you know R5, you know that R4+R5 (a now known value) in parallel with R3 is one half of your voltage divider (with R2) that takes 16V down to 14.5V.

Comment: This can't be done with the initial values you give for R2 and R4.  You have 1.5 volts across the 10K R2.  That current can't possibly produce 13.5 volts across 1 K R4, and you don't say how much of the 150 uA through R2 is going to the 14.5 volt load.

Comment: what is the point of having R3 in the circuit?

Comment: @KH , I assumed those values for R2 & R4. But now i will design them as per LM358 input current , i.e. 50mA .

Comment: @jsotola Later on I will replace those with POTs, of designed values, calibrate the battery as well as OPAmp Input Voltage.

Comment: @Peter Bennett   You are right, now I will design them as per LM358 input current , i.e. 50mA .

Comment: @KH:  A regulator isn't the right choice, here.  This circuit apppears to be intended to read the battery voltage with the ADC of a microcontroller.  A regulator  isn't appropriate.

Comment: @Israr:  Use a single divider to bring the 16V down to 1V.  It is simpler to calculate, it uses fewer parts, and it will be more accurate.

Comment: @JRE , not MCU , but OPAmp. This 1V will go to OPAmp Non-Inverting Input. Inverting Input will have 1V reference. Just now i realized that 1V Divider will never source any current except few microamps of leakage input current may be. This will sink current from 5V OPAmp output in between the Hysteresis voltage transitions. Now 
remain the values of R3 & R5.

Comment: @JRE 14.5 V from Battery is the Indicator of Full Battery Voltage and this will go to control circuit from OPAmp. In house hold Inverter Circuit they provide 2 POTS , 1 for 14.5 V setting, another for 1V OPAmp input. This circuit is for that.

Comment: Then use two separate voltage dividers.

Comment: I think i should first most consider that small amount of current sink and calculate the values of resistances.

Comment: Output source current of LM358 is 20mA. 10mA sink current for 1V divider will be sufficiant. Finally 1V divider will source leakge current of say 50uA and it will sink 10mA.I think this should be enough to design those resistors for 1mA source and 10mA sink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMQH9k.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$\text{I}_1=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3\tag1$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, we know the values of \$\text{V}_\text{i}\$, \$\text{R}_1\$, \$\text{R}_3\$, \$\text{V}_1\$, and \$\text{V}_2\$. So coloring the things we know red, we see:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\color{red}{\text{V}_\text{i}}-\color{red}{\text{V}_1}}{\color{red}{\text{R}_1}}=\frac{\color{red}{\text{V}_1}}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\color{red}{\text{V}_1}-\color{red}{\text{V}_2}}{\color{red}{\text{R}_3}}\\
\\
\frac{\color{red}{\text{V}_\text{i}}-\color{red}{\text{V}_1}}{\color{red}{\text{R}_1}}=\frac{\color{red}{\text{V}_1}}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\color{red}{\text{V}_2}}{\text{R}_4}
\end{cases}\tag4
$$

So, we have two equations and two unknowns, namely \$\text{R}_2\$ and \$\text{R}_4\$. Using your values, we see that:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{16-\frac{29}{2}}{10000}=\frac{\frac{29}{2}}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\frac{29}{2}-1}{1000}\\
\\
\frac{16-\frac{29}{2}}{10000}=\frac{\frac{29}{2}}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{1}{\text{R}_4}
\end{cases}\tag5
$$

It is not hard to solve this (so I let you do that). I used a simple Mathematica code to solve this:

```
In[1]:=Vi = 16;
V1 = 29/2;
V2 = 1;
R1 = 10000;
R3 = 1000;
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == I2 + I3, I1 == (Vi - V1)/R1, I2 == V1/R2, 
   I3 == (V1 - V2)/R3, I3 == V2/R4}, {I1, I2, I3, R2, R4}]]

Out[1]={{I1 -> 3/20000, I2 -> -(267/20000), I3 -> 27/2000, 
  R2 -> -(290000/267), R4 -> 2000/27}}
```

So, we get:

$$\text{R}_2=-\frac{290000}{267}\approx-1086.14\space\Omega\space\space\space\wedge\space\space\space\text{R}_4=\frac{2000}{27}\approx74.0741\space\Omega\tag6$$

> Which is not possible because the resistance must be bigger than zero.